# TeXlipse "Preview Document" not building document from Eclipse - Mac OSX

Tags: mactex, texlipse, eclipse

When I use `Latex > Preview Document` in Eclipse (with TeXlipse and MacTex installed), nothing happens, despite being able to run *latex* or *pdflatex* in commandline to build a perfectly functional PDF that I can open in Preview. Nothing at all from Eclipse: no .aux or .pdf file (in either my `$HOME` directory or project directory), Preview doesn't open, and no error messages.

*Anyone have a thought as to why Eclipse won't build the document?*

I'm running Eclipse version 2.0.0.20130613-0530 in Mac OSX 10.10.2 (Yosemite). My Eclipse preferences for TeXlipse are set up so all the programs in Builder Settings are "Latex program (`/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin/latex`)" and so on. I have the Viewer Settings set up with the top option using "Viewer command: /usr/bin/open" and "Viewer arguments: %file" with PDF format, which should work to open the file in Preview by default.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I figured it out. I had set everything up correctly above, but my test project was set up with "dvi" as the output format instead of "pdf."